# Flow between sets of vertices

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am confused about what does flow mean in the context of set of vertices.

Say `f(s,V)`, s is source and V a set of vertices. Means /sum over v /belongs V with s.

But `f(X,Y)` where both X and Y are sets. What does that mean?
do you sum between each pair?

In this context, why is `f(X,X)=0`, `X` is say `{a,b}`.

Comment: Generally it means that if you select any cut that separates X from Y, the net flow across the cut is f.

Answer (score 0):

The definition for flow in the case of multiple sources / sinks is similar to the one for single source / sink.

Each source should have 0 incoming flow. Each sink should have 0 outgoing flow. All other nodes should have equal incoming and outgoing flow.

---

Interestingly, the flow in the case of multiple source/sink nodes can be reduced to the single source - single sink case.

Let us assume we have a graph **G**, a set of source nodes denoted as **X**, and a set of sink nodes denoted as **Y**.

We will create a new graph, **G'**, which is almost identical to **G**, except that it has two additional nodes, denoted as **s** and **t**, with the following connections:

- **s** has an outgoing edge towards each node in **X**. Set these edges to have infinite capacity.
- **t** has an incoming edge from each node in **X**. Also set these edges to have infinite capacity.

Then, there is a direct, one-to-one correspondence between any flow in **G** from the source set **X** to the sink set **Y** to any flow in **G'** from the source **s** to the sink **t**.

And, as a corollary, the max-flow in **G'** from **s** to **t** also represents the max-flow value in **G**, from **X** to **Y**.